# syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using c# and this error is becoming headache for me. I do not know how to solve this error . 
can anyone help me to solve this. Here is the code

```
try
{
    string MyConnection2 = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\DELL\Documents\db1.mdb";
    //Display query  
    string Query = "select  riq_num , department, item_name , item_unit , no_of_stock_out , itemtype from outputdet1 where riq_num = " + textBox2.Text + " or department= '" + comboBox1.Text + " ' or item_name= '" + textBox4.Text + "' or item_unit= '" + comboBox2.Text + "' or no_of_stock_out = " + textBox6.Text + " or itemtype = '" + comboBox3.Text + "' ; ";

    OleDbConnection MyConn2 = new OleDbConnection(MyConnection2);
    OleDbCommand MyCommand2 = new OleDbCommand(Query, MyConn2);
    MyConn2.Open();

    //For offline connection we will use  MySqlDataAdapter class.  
    OleDbDataAdapter MyAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    MyAdapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand2;
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    MyAdapter.Fill(dTable);

    // here i have assign dTable object to the dataGridView1 object to display data.         
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;       
    MyConn2.Close();
}
    // OleDbCommand MyCommand2 = new OleDbCommand(Query, MyConn2);
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: On which line is there an error?

Comment: it does not go inside try block !

Comment: it directly goes to catch block !

Comment: You will have an easier time if you parameterise your query

Comment: i also check after removing ; from query line .

Comment: can you help me out how can i apply parameterise query ? @DavidPilkington

Comment: `TextBox.Text` returns string, you're certainly passing string without enclosing it with single quotes to `riq_num` column (side note: use parameterized query to avoid SQL injection!).

Comment: Put a break point on the first line of the try block, and step through with the debugger until you get the exception.

Comment: "it directly goes to catch block !" - You put the exception message in a messagebox in that block ... *read it*. I also recommend to output the stacktrace and add that to the question.

Comment: If `textBox2` or `textBox6` is empty, the sql statement will have a syntax error.

Comment: try to read the error

Comment: when i enclosing it in single quotes it gives me this error !
syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'riq_num= ' 'or department =' 'or item_name= ' 'or item_unit =' 'or no_of_stock_out = ' or itemtype = '''

Comment: As said before, parameterise your query!

Comment: Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types

Comment: how can i parameterise it ? @wimh

Comment: @jerry Read the links I gave. There are examples on how to use parameters.

Comment: For various reasons your approach is very bad style: At first you should not construct your query with control properties (e.g. textBox4.Text; by the way give the controls a self-explaining name), but using some kind of entity classes or at least wrap your code into a paramterized method. At second you should explicitly handle cases of your parameters being empty or so. Also it would be fine to use a finally block for being sure everything is closed well in the end. Last use the SqlParameter approach for a state of the art query

Answer (score 4):

I assumed that `textBox2.Text` & `textBox6.Text` return a string from textbox control, so that `OleDbCommand` will throwing exception when it contains **empty value or any non-numeric string** since it will form invalid SQL statement. Use parameterized query like this example:

```
string Query = @"select riq_num, department, item_name, item_unit, no_of_stock_out, itemtype 
                 from outputdet1 
                 where riq_num = @riq_num
                 or department= @department 
                 or item_name= @item_name
                 or item_unit= @item_unit
                 or no_of_stock_out = @no_of_stock_out 
                 or itemtype = @itemtype";

using (OleDbConnection MyConn2 = new OleDbConnection(MyConnection2))
{
    using (OleDbCommand MyCommand2 = new OleDbCommand(Query, MyConn2))
    {
        MyConn2.Open();

        MyCommand2.Parameters.Add("@riq_num", textBox2.Text);
        MyCommand2.Parameters.Add("@department", comboBox1.Text);
        MyCommand2.Parameters.Add("@item_name", textBox4.Text);
        MyCommand2.Parameters.Add("@item_unit", comboBox2.Text);
        MyCommand2.Parameters.Add("@no_of_stock_out", textBox6.Text);
        MyCommand2.Parameters.Add("@itemtype", comboBox3.Text);

        // execute the query here
    }
}
```

Remember that `using` statements used to dispose OLEDB connection immediately after it has closed so that GC can free up resources.

**Additional note:**

`OleDbParameter` works with parameter order instead of named parameters, hence ensure that the parameters are declared **in their proper order from first to last**.